# Exportar proyecto WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Estoy intentando exportar mi proyecto `winForm` a un instalador, o un portable.

He probado de varias maneras, y lo que presiento es que sucede algun tipo de eror a la hora de cargar los cursores personalizados;

```
 Cursor = GestionCursores.Create(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "..//..//Resources//Cursores//normal.ani"));
```

Ejecutando el .exe de la carpeta `Debug` del proyecto, funciona perfectamente, pero una vez que saco el contenido no puede encontrar la ruta a los elementos, modificando la ruta de tal manera que si los encuentre, ejecuto el `.exe` y no sucede nada.

También hice la típica publicación que genera un instalable con `ClickOnce`, pero me da el mismo error es decir, no mostrar nada.

Por ultimo también intente con las herramientas `Visual studio Installer` pero con el mismo éxito.

En los procesos se muestra mi aplicación en ejecución durante 3 segundos y se cierra automáticamente, no mostrando ningún error, y no se por donde tirar.

Comment: Estás usando ClickOnce?

Comment: Si, perdon a eso es a lo que me referia con la tipica publicacion de .net

Comment: La manera mas sencilla de crear un instalador es desde el propio visual studio. Vas a las propiedades del proyecto y de ahi a publicar. Esto te crea un instalador. Para poder acceder a los recursos, te hablo de memoria, pero tal vez debas acceder a las propiedades de la imagen y en accion de compilación poner "recurso incrustado", si no recuerdo mal

Comment: Si, se lo que dices tengo todas las imágenes con la propiedad en `Copiar siempre` voy a modificar la pregunta para que veas el error que me sale.

Comment: Los archivos de imagenes y los cursores no tienen porque estar fuera de tu proyecto, puedes agregarlo como un recurso y acceder a el dentro de tu app cuando desees. No tienes ni que hacer un instalador para ello

Comment: Hmm..eso si que es raro, puede ser un problema de permisos. Pincha en "detalles" a ver si te da algo mas de información

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas te refieres a usar en la busqueda de las imagenes `Resources.imagen;` con `using proyecto.Properties;` ??

Comment: @Pikoh salen errores del palo `System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException`

Answer (score 1):

Use el proyecto de instalación de Visual Studio. El proyecto de instalación puede incluir automáticamente la configuración de .NET framework en su paquete de instalación:

Aquí está mi paso a paso para la aplicación de formularios de Windows:

1. Crear proyecto de instalación. Puede usar el Asistente de configuración.

   [image]
2. Seleccione el tipo de proyecto.

   [image]
3. Seleccionar salida.

   [image]
4. Hit Finish.
5. Abra las propiedades del proyecto de instalación.

   [image]
6. Eligió incluir .NET framework.

   [image]
7. Proyecto de instalación de compilación
8. Verificar salida

   [image]

**Otro método:**

Puede utilizar un proyecto de instalación de [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) (integrarlo fácilmente con Visual Studio).

- Puede hacer casi toda su personalización en el proyecto de
  configuración [agregando acciones
  personalizadas](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects).
- WIX (instalador de ventana xml) es la mejor opción. Puedes hacer una
  personalización completa desde wix pero lleva algo de tiempo
  entender, ya que está totalmente basada en XML. Las configuraciones
  de Microsoft Office 2007 y posteriores se basan en wix.

La diferencia entre wix y el proyecto de instalación es que usted tiene más control sobre la GUI de la configuración en wix que el proyecto de configuración y wix permite mucha más personalización que el proyecto de instalación. Echa un vistazo a [este tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects) paso a paso para wix.

Comment: Siguiendo el tutorial que has propuesto me da error a la hora de ejecutar el .exe dice que no puede encontrar la ruta que especifique en los cursores personalizados. Intentaré hacer lo que has propuesto tambien con WIX.

Comment: mmm es extraño, pero para ese error que mencionas [mira esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7163252/8933039) creo que puede ayudarte con respecto a las rutas. (Traduce la respuesta)

Comment: Prueba [esto](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/) o también puede probar hacerlo con [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: Más información al respecto [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7233456/8933039) también [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438069/8933039) es cuanto de mi parte. Saliudos!